# How to make agent flock in their group using BOIDS rule in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo, flock, boids

Here is what I want to do:

1. I need all agents **move forward** **in a group** by using BOIDS rule
2. I want them to be **able to turn around** after they meet the wall (my world is not wrap, they can't penetrate the wall to reach the other side of the world)

here is my code:

```
globals [nearest-teammates teammmembers]

turtles-own [ myteamset teamID myID teammatesID ]

to setup-groups

  let teamCounter 1 
  ask turtles [
    if myteamset = nobody [
      let possible-teammates other turtles with [ myteamset = nobody ]
      ifelse count possible-teammates > 1 [
        set myteamset ( turtle-set self n-of 2 possible-teammates )
        let ids sort [myID] of myteamset
        set teammmembers myteamset
        set nearest-teammates min-one-of myteamset[distance myself]

        let tempteam teamCounter         
        set teamCounter teamCounter + 1
        ask myteamset [
          set teammatesID ids
          set myteamset teammmembers
          set teamID tempteam
        ]

      ] [
        show "Not enough turtles to make a new team!"
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

flocking part:

```
to move-in-groups

  let teamNumbers remove-duplicates [teamID] of turtles
  foreach teamNumbers [                         
    ask one-of turtles with [ teamID = ? ] [
      if myteamset != nobody [
        ask myteamset [
        set  heading mean-heading [ heading ] of myteamset
         ifelse distance one-of turtles with [ teamID = ? ] < 3
         [separate]
         [align
           cohere]]
          fd 1 ]]]
end
```

helpers code

```
to-report mean-heading [ headings ]
  let mean-x mean map sin headings
  let mean-y mean map cos headings
  report atan mean-x mean-y
end

to align  
  turn-towards average-flockmate-heading max-align-turn
end

to cohere  
  turn-towards average-heading-towards-flockmates max-cohere-turn
end


to separate  
  turn-away ([heading] of nearest-teammates) max-separate-turn
end

to turn-away [new-heading max-turn]  
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings heading new-heading) max-turn
end

to-report average-heading-towards-flockmates  
  let x-component mean [sin (towards myself + 180)] of nearest-teammates
  let y-component mean [cos (towards myself + 180)] of nearest-teammates
  ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
    [ report heading ]
    [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end

to-report average-flockmate-heading  
  let x-component sum [dx] of nearest-teammates
  let y-component sum [dy] of nearest-teammates
  ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
    [ report heading ]
    [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end

to turn-at-most [turn max-turn]  
  ifelse abs turn > max-turn
    [ ifelse turn > 0
        [ rt max-turn ]
        [ lt max-turn ] ]
    [ rt turn ]
end

to turn-towards [new-heading max-turn]  
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings new-heading heading) max-turn
end
```

The error I get:

```
SUM expected input to be a list but got the number -0.961261695938319 instead.
error while turtle 4 running SUM
  called by procedure AVERAGE-FLOCKMATE-HEADING
  called by procedure ALIGN
  called by (command task from: procedure MOVE-IN-GROUPS)
  called by procedure MOVE-IN-GROUPS
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

What should I do? I need help...  .·´¯`(>▂<)´¯`·.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting happens on this line:

```
let x-component sum [dx] of nearest-teammates
```

NetLogo is telling you that you tried to pass a single number to `sum` instead of passing it a list. How could that happen? It would happen if `nearest-teammates` contained a single agent instead of an agentset.

So let's look at where you define `nearest-teammates`:

```
set nearest-teammates min-one-of myteamset[distance myself]
```

Can you see the problem? You're using [`min-one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-one-of), which does give you a single agent!

How could you get, for example, the 10 closest agents instead of just the closest one? Fortunately, NetLogo has a primitive that does just that: [`min-n-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-n-of). Here is how you would use it:

```
set nearest-teammates min-n-of 10 myteamset [ distance myself ]
```

Replace `10` with the number of teammates you want, of course.

Comment: Yess, thats itt~ now I understand where the problem is. But after I changed it, there's a new error in `to turn-away [new-heading max-turn]
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings heading new-heading) max-turn` and the error stated `SUBTRACT-HEADINGS expected input to be a number but got the list [346 213 4] instead.` I tried to find where the list come from to no avail :'(

Comment: I'm sure we can figure it out, but I think you'll need to open a separate question for that and post a bit more code so we can where `turn-away` is called from...